# Почему не срабатывает декоратор python (flask)

Tags: python, веб-программирование, функции, flask, декоратор

Я написал декоратор, который должен проверять наличие прав у текущего пользователя и если у него есть права модератора, то он может зайти в раздел и внести правки или добавить что-либо, иначе вывести ошибку 403.

Сама функция:

```
from flask_login import current_user


@check_rights(current_user)
@cars.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    form = AddCarForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        car = Car()
        car.concern_id = form.concern.data.id
        car.model = form.model.data
        car.price_per_day = form.price_per_day.data
        car.description = form.description.data

        if form.pic.data:
            car.pic = save_picture(form.pic.data)

        db.session.add(car)
        db.session.commit()

        print(car.pic)

        flash(f'{car.concern.title} {car.model} was successfully added to db!', 'info')
        return redirect(url_for('cars.index'))

    return render_template('cars/add.html', form=form)
```

И декоратор написанный в отдельном модуле:

```
def check_rights(current_user):
    def dec(wrapped):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            if current_user.superuser:
                return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                abort(403)
        return inner
    return dec
```

Что здесь не так? Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить, заранее спасибо.

p.s. Собственно проблема заключается в том, что любой пользователь вне зависимости от прав всё равно может зайти в раздел и добавлять и исправлять всё подряд.

Comment: Поменяйте декораторы местами

Comment: @andreymal
Я поменял местами декораторы функции так что они теперь стоят в таком порядке:
@cars.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@check_rights(current_user)
Но к сожалению теперь выдаётся ошибка, что не удалось преобразовать маршрут к cars.add. Если я правильно вас понял

Comment: А теперь это похоже ошибка в вашем декораторе, который не копирует информацию из оригинальной функции в функцию-враппер. Используйте functools.wraps